# 12v circuit with push button needs to auto press and hold

Tags: relay, timer

I need to create a circuit which closes a relay for 10 seconds (activates an external circuit by completing it (the same as if I fit a push button) and then releases the relay for 1 second, before making it again for 10 - and repeats forever.

Any advise on what components (etc) to use here, would be fantastic.

Comment: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html

Comment: look for "556 intravalometer" circuits. mims has a good one.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit can be just a microcontroller driving a relay:

[image]

The rest is firmware.

In this case the MCLR/GP3 pin is configured in the GP3 role with internal pullup enabled.